# How to change primary partition to extended without formatting

Tags: partitioning

I have 4 primary partitions already, and I want to make a partition for installing ubuntu, but I get the error that there can't be more than 4 primary partitions, is there a way that I can put two of the existing partitions inside an extended partition, without loosing any data?
Edit: all the partitions are NTFS.

Comment: So, you still haven't installed Ubuntu, Right?

Comment: No. I haven't yet.

Comment: You can't do a direct conversion, as far as I know, you'd have to make clone copies of one (or more) of the ntfs partitions, delete it/them, create an extended partition in its/their place, create a/some logical partitions and restore the cloned partition(s) to it/those. Mind not to do this with a partition that holds the main operating system, I don't think windows likes being booted off a logical partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't installed Ubuntu yet, and still on windows then you may want to take a look at this.  [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm).

It will allow you to do the conversion without loosing any data, and its free