# Partitioning for Ubuntu Install

Tags: installation, partitioning, boot-partition

I shrunk my windows 8 partition to create a partition for dual boot of Ubuntu. On the Live usb I opened up GParted to format that unallocated space into ext 4. The problem is I have four primary partitions already and cannot make another primary partition. The four partitions are labeled sda1 SYSTEM, sda2  with no label, sda3 RECOVERY, and sda4 HP_TOOLS. I am new to this area, but would love to try Ubuntu and this has thrown me a curveball. I am not quite sure what to do from here.

Comment: upload the gparted screenshot to `imgur.com` and post the link here.

Comment: four primary partitions , why?? you can make logical instead, even install ubuntu on logical.. why four primary partition ??

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) partition manager to convert one of your primary partition to extended logical (by [Mitch](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch) in reply to [How to change primary partition to extended without formatting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161475/how-to-change-primary-partition-to-extended-without-formatting)).

You would then shrink the logical partition, and create the partitions for your Ubuntu installation. For an [Ubuntu installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/howto-installation.html) you'll need at least one partition (ext4/ext3/ext2) for the ***root ( / ) partition*** ([at least 5GB, at most 30GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)). A ***[swap partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)*** of size equal to or up to 3 times the size of your RAM is recommended (if you're short on RAM).

Comment: my RAM size is 8gb.did i need to create 24gb space for swap partition?

Comment: Do you? (I think you would not, unless 8GB is insufficient for your RAM consumption.) And I'm sure you know the purpose of _swap_! Well, I have 1GB of RAM and I need swap. But I'm curious do you optimal use of 8GB RAM. (updated my answer though)

Comment: 2*x, or 3*x is out of trend as of now, just equal swap and physical ram would be better . for new computers 2x is just more then enough you dont need to put one more x.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of computers that come with Windows 8 pre-installed use the GUID Partition Table (GPT), which doesn't suffer from a 4-primary-partition limit. In fact, GPT doesn't make a distinction between primary, extended, and logical partitions; you've just got "partitions" (with no qualifier), although GParted and some other tools insist on applying the "primary" adjective to GPT partitions.

If you've installed Windows 8 yourself or adjusted it to boot in BIOS mode with MBR partitions, though, you'll have that issue. You may be able to work around it by using [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) (included in the Ubuntu `gdisk` package) to convert one partition to logical form. This will also create an extended partition, which you'll be able to resize and then create new logical partitions within the extended partition. There are caveats and limits to what FixParts can do, though. Read its Web page for details.